# Samsung Galaxy S and Hyperterminal

Tags: command, galaxy, at-command, hyperterminal

When connecting Samsung Galaxy S via USB to hyperterminal, I cannot retrieve any messages or send messages. The commands "AT", "AT+CMGF=1" work, and "AT+CMPI=?" return different memories available. But when I try to execute the following command: AT+CMPI="SM" (or any other memory) I get an error. In addition when I try AT+CMGS="..." it gives an error too. What can it be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i landed here.. no answers yet if that would be of an help for future googlers

http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp is a great reference.

```
AT
OK
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGW="+21291234567"
> A simple demo of SMS text messaging.
+CMGW: 1

OK
AT+CMSS=1
+CMSS: 20

OK
```

tested on samsung s3...